# self adjoint linear operator and integration

Tags: operator-theory, adjoint-operators

is this formula correct ??

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} Lf(x)\delta (x-1)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)L^{\dagger}\delta(x-1) $$

here $ L $ is a linear operator and $ L^{\dagger}$ is its formal adjoint

for excample can someone provide some help whenever $ L = \Theta ^{n} $ and $ \Theta = x \frac{d}{dx} $ to find its self adjoint ??

also for example if i set $ f(x)= Li_{-s}(x) $  polyologarithm i guess the integral in the end should be equal to $ \zeta (s) $

Comment: It is symbolically correct, many of the "typical" linear operators that occur in these sorts of problems would not be well-defined on a Dirac distribution.

Comment: consider an opeartor that includes only $ x $ and $ \partial _{x} $